# Why is this simple primitive shaded so weirdly?

Tags: shaders, normals

I made sure everything is quads , I've checked the normals, I've unmade and remade all the faces, no luck. Why is the shading still so weird?

All I did to create it before I started trying to fix this was make a circle and reduce it to 3 sides to make a triangle, then extrude it along the z axis, and fill the top and bottom off with faces.

[image: editor view in blender]

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have the mesh set to Smooth shading. This will attempt to generate consistent normals around the edges and vertices to blend in with the adjacent geometry. Set the shading to 'Flat' and each face will have consistent shading (with hard edges).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your face normals, you only have 5 faces on your object. You should have 12 if you're going to have all quads (see below):

[image]

You can see how many verts, edges, and faces your mesh has by looking in the bottom left corner in Edit Mode. Try and match the numbers I have here:

[image]

I suspect where you went wrong was in dividing up the extruded triangle. You can create edges by highlighting two vertices and pressing **F** but the created edge will not split the underlying face in two. To actually split a face in two, you should use the **J** key to "Join."